# AH02579: Init: Private key not found - SSL apache2 ubuntu 16

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, ssl

having some issues with ssl. first time installing it on linux. I can do it very easy with windows. but linux I am having a hard time.

My current server

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
RAM: 2GB
Web Server: Apache2
```

The error.log file is below

```
[Wed Dec 20 11:47:49.557544 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 3722] AH02579: Init: Private key not found
[Wed Dec 20 11:47:49.557627 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 3722] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Dec 20 11:47:49.557648 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 3722] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Wed Dec 20 11:47:49.557663 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 3722] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Dec 20 11:47:49.557678 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 3722] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=RSA)
[Wed Dec 20 11:47:49.557693 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 3722] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Wed Dec 20 11:47:49.557706 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 3722] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Dec 20 11:47:49.557721 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 3722] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
[Wed Dec 20 11:47:49.557938 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3722] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
[Wed Dec 20 11:47:49.557950 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3722] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key crm.ngm-inc.com:443:0, check /internalsites/certs/mycsr.csr
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

This is the default-ssl.conf in siltes enables/available

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        # Admin Email
        ServerAdmin myemail@domain.com

        # Document Location of site
        DocumentRoot "/mysslsites/site1"
        ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com

        # Log files
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile  /internalsites/certs/mycert.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /internalsites/certs/mycsr.csr


        SSLCertificateChainFile /internalsites/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt


        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>


    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

commands I have ran

```
#enable SSL
sudo a2enmod ssl
# create the symlink between available and enabled
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
# restart the service of apache to have changes take affect
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Some sides notes

1. mycsr.csr - came from my IIS server that I generated the key from
2. the mycert.crt - was named an encrypted name from godaddy
3. I AM A COMPLETE NOOB WHEN IT COMES TO SSL and APACHE2 haha

Comment: It seems that `mycsr.csr` isn't the private key file but the certificate signing request? The correct key file should start with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`. `mycert.crt` should start with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`. Other then that, this question is probably off topic here, better suited for [su]

Comment: and it does. I used it to rekey my ssl just 20 mins ago

Comment: It's from IIS so it's a little different. It looks like this

-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

Comment: Yes, that's the certificate signing request, not the private key. You need the private key, which is not part of a csr but should be in a separate file.

Comment: In IIS it's the same. When I go to goDaddy and say "ReKey my certificate" I use this text to "ReKey" maybe you want to enlighten me in IIS where a key is?

Comment: I don't really have any experience with IIS, so I don't know. A quick search got me to [this](https://docs.druva.com/Knowledge_Base/inSync/How_To/Using_Microsoft_IIS_to_generate_CSR_and_Private_Key), step 2 and 3 seem promising.

Comment: Yeah I was just looking at that document. I am able to export the certificate out of IIS. It will create a pfx with a password. Is this what I am going for?

Comment: No, you want the `.key` file at the end of step 3

Comment: Ok. So I got my key. It has this at the top. Should I remove it? Above
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: Bag Attributes
    Microsoft Local Key set: <No Values>
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
    friendlyName: le-6658f6f6-d127-4cb1-87fa-7fd14007b4fc
    Microsoft CSP Name: Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider
Key Attributes
    X509v3 Key Usage: 10

Comment: `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----` means it's pkcs8 formatted. try `openssl pkcs8 -in input.key -out output.key` on that. All those different formats really are confusing

Comment: Thanks mata. I am just going to move the site over to my IIS server. As it won't take another ip and I can manage it easier. Thanks for your help :) 

I have learned a ton from this experience though  haha